# How do I grab info from this json file?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm trying to grab some numbers from this json file, but I don't how to do it correctly. This is the json file I am trying to gather information from:

http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2016-17&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=

I've been trying to get this code to work, but I can't figure it out:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)


data["rowSet"] ["1610612737"] ["Atlanta Hawks"]
```

I'm trying to get the statistics from each team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Python script should do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

with open('leaguedashteamstats.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    # extract headers names
    headers = data['resultSets'][0]['headers']

    # extract raw json rows
    raw_rows = data['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

    team_stats = []
    for row in raw_rows:
        print row[1] # prints team name

        # mixes header names and values and prints them out
        for (header, value) in zip(headers, row):
            print header, value
        print '\n'
```

Both data and code can be seen here:
https://gist.github.com/cevaris/24d0b7d97677667aedb14059a6959da1#file-1-team-stats-output

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this code doesn't contain any validation, but it should lead you in the right direction:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)


for rs in data.get('resultSets'):
    for r_ in [r for r in rs.get('rowSet') if r[1] == 'Atlanta Hawks']:
        print(r_)
```

You basically need to determine specific keys that you are going to loop through, or obtain.

This should hopefully get you to where  you need to be.